# How to drop the top 3 highest value in a column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with various data and I want to drop some rows with the top 3 highest value in a column.

My approach:

First sort the data frame by the column "Coal":

`energyDataRed <- energyData[order(-energyData$Coal), ]`

[image]

And then drop the top 3 columns with:

`energyDataRed <- energyDataRed[-1:-2, ]`

It works but I think there is a better way, right?

Comment: You could try `subset(energyDataRed, rank(Coal) < max(rank(Coal)) - 2)`. But consult the function documentation for how this will handle tied values.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without a reproducible example, but you can try to use `slice_min()` to keep the n-3 smallest values of the column "Coal" (where n is the number of rows of the dataset).

```r
library(dplyr)

yourdata %>% 
  slice_min(order_by = Coal, n = nrow(yourdata)-3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to do, but here are several ways of dropping `rows` from a `data.frame` based on the three maximum values of a particular `column` using `base R`.  I imagine far simpler approaches exist in `base R`.  But these were the first to come to my mind.

```
set.seed(1234)

aa <- sample(10,10,replace=TRUE)
bb <- sample(100,10,replace=TRUE)
cc <- sample(seq(8,22,by=2),10,replace=TRUE)
dd <- sample(seq(-100,-50,by=5),10,replace=TRUE)

my.data <- data.frame(aa,bb,cc,dd)
my.data
#   aa bb cc  dd
#1  10 90 22 -95
#2   6 70 14 -65
#3   5 79 22 -50
#4   9 78 12 -85
#5   5 14 14 -90
#6   6 56 20 -70
#7   4 62 20 -60
#8   2  4 16 -90
#9   7  4 10 -75
#10  6 21 16 -85

# The top three values of cc are 22 (twice), 20 (twice) and 16 (twice)

# If you want to drop rows in which cc = 22, 22, or 20
my.data2 <- my.data[-which(cc %in% sort(cc,decreasing=TRUE)[1:3]),]
my.data2
#   aa bb cc  dd
#2   6 70 14 -65
#4   9 78 12 -85
#5   5 14 14 -90
#8   2  4 16 -90
#9   7  4 10 -75
#10  6 21 16 -85

# If you want to drop all rows in which cc = 22, 20, or 16
my.data3 <- my.data[!my.data$cc %in% rev(as.numeric(names(table(cc))))[1:3],]
my.data3
#  aa bb cc  dd
#2  6 70 14 -65
#4  9 78 12 -85
#5  5 14 14 -90
#9  7  4 10 -75

# If you want to drop rows in which cc = 22, 22, or the first 20
my.data4 <- my.data[is.na(c(match((nrow(my.data)+1) - rank(my.data$cc, ties.method = c("last")), c(1:3)))),]
my.data4
#   aa bb cc  dd
#2   6 70 14 -65
#4   9 78 12 -85
#5   5 14 14 -90
#7   4 62 20 -60
#8   2  4 16 -90
#9   7  4 10 -75
#10  6 21 16 -85
```